Cardano fullnode not syncing
I am using the following config files after downloading cardano-node & cardano-cli from GitHub
However, when I run the following command to run cardano-node:
 cardano-node run \
   --topology $HOME/config-files/topology.json \
   --database-path $HOME/config-files/db \
   --socket-path $HOME/config-files/db/node.socket \
   --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
   --port 3001 \
   --config $HOME/config-files/config.json

It tries to find peers but I get a typical error:
cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:64] [2024-07-08 13:32:40.65 UTC] TracePromoteColdFailed 3 0 3.15.67.21:3001 158.938876633654s Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

and
[ed-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:64] [2024-07-08 13:48:43.75 UTC] TracePromoteColdPeers 3 0 (fromList [3.78.8.215:3001])
[ed-:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:710] [2024-07-08 13:48:43.75 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[ed-:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:710] [2024-07-08 13:48:43.75 UTC] TrConnectError (Just 127.0.0.1:3001) 3.78.8.215:3001 Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

Also when I do the query:
   cardano-cli query tip --mainnet --socket-path $HOME/config-files/db/node.socket

I get:
{
    "block": 0,
    "epoch": 0,
    "era": "Byron",
    "hash": "d2d90d10993b3eb309f5485a5413cb9c9fe4f088e79b7b4e815dbbe8fcb8e4b7",
    "slot": 0,
    "slotInEpoch": 0,
    "slotsToEpochEnd": 21600,
    "syncProgress": "0.00"
}

Please help us setting up a full node (not a validator though). What is missing in it?
Thanks.

I tested this version and it started syncing on mainnet. The error Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: invalid argument (Invalid argument) states that there may be an issue with one or more of the arguments you are providing in the CLI command is invalid. Can you check the arguments you are providing most likely an issue with $HOME environment variables? This one works for me:
./bin/cardano-node run --topology topology.json --database-path db --socket-path node.socket --port 6001 --config config.json

Thanks; yes, there was the issue with $HOME variables.
